# EF Code First creating redundant nonclustered index for 1-to-0..1 relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-migrations

Consider the following entities with a `1:0..1` relationship, where a `Foo` may have a related `FooBar`, and `FooBar.Id` is both the primary key and a foreign key to `Foo.Id`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual FooBar FooBar {get; set;}
}

public class FooBar
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasOptional(e => e.FooBar).WithRequired();
```

This works well, except the generated migration code in `Up()` contains a *redundant index* on `FooBar.Id`:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.FooBar",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Foo", t => t.Id)
    .Index(t => t.Id);
```

As you can see, the call to `PrimaryKey` will create a clustered index, and there's an additional `Index` call scaffolded from the foreign key. Indeed in the database, I see both indexes. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the nonclustered index will never be used in this scenario and its *only* function would be to simply take up space.

I assume this is happening because the foreign key in the framework has no knowledge of the primary key. So, is there any way to get EF to realize the column already has an index from the primary key and not scaffold an additional index from the foreign key (without manually modifying the code in the migration's `Up()` method and removing the `.Index()` call)?

Comment: I can't think of any available method to affect this behavior.